# document starting point in DocBook documents

Tags: xml, docbook, docbook-5

I need to know a list of document starting points in Docbook such as book, article, etc. Can someone please give a list of such starting points? Is it illegal to start with elements such as chapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have chapter as the start (root) element.

The valid root elements in DocBook 5 documents are listed in [DocBook 5: The Definitive Guide](http://docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/ch02.html#roots):

> ... only elements with an info element can be root elements, but not every element with an info element is currently included. In DocBook V5.0 the following elements are available: acknowledgements, appendix, article, bibliography, book, chapter, colophon, dedication, glossary, index, para, part, preface, refentry, reference, refsect1, refsect2, refsect3, refsection, sect1, sect2, sect3, sect4, sect5, section, set, setindex, and toc.